# php/mysql. Is there mysql function to detect if at least 2 certain words exists in at least one mysql row-field

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I have php array `$php_arr_to_check = array("green", "red", "blue");`

And have many mysql rows like this

```
Id  |  TextToCheckIn 
______________________
1   |  green brown blue
2   |  black yellow white red
3   |  yellow green black red grey white
```

Want as if to loop `$php_arr_to_check` through each row in column `TextToCheckIn` and return `Id` where, for example, at least 2 words from `$php_arr_to_check` exists in `TextToCheckIn`.

Is it possible? Does any mysql function exist?

Here is example with php (what I want to get)

```
$php_arr_to_check = array("green", "red", "blue");
echo '<pre>', print_r($php_arr_to_check, true), '</pre> php_arr_to_check <br/>';

$mysql_rows = array(
array("green", "brown", "blue"),
array("black", "yellow", "white", "red"),
array("yellow", "green", "black", "red", "grey", "white")
);
echo '<pre>', print_r($mysql_rows, true), '</pre> mysql_rows <br/>';

foreach( $mysql_rows as $one_row ){
//echo count(array_intersect($php_arr_to_check, $one_row)). ' count array_intersect __ <br/>';
if( count(array_intersect($php_arr_to_check, $one_row)) > 1 ){
$arr_with_count_matches[] = count(array_intersect($php_arr_to_check, $one_row));
$maches_exist = true;
}
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($arr_with_count_matches, true), '</pre> arr_with_count_matches <br/>';
```

Want to get the same result comparing php array to mysql column.

Any ideas how to do that (without `LIKE`)? May be with `MATCH AGAINST` somehow?

Before i used below, but got as if false positives....

```
SELECT 
Id FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (TextToCheckIn) AGAINST (?) LIMIT 1
```

Will try

```
SELECT 
Id FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (SUBSTRING_INDEX(TextToCheckIn, ' ', 3)) AGAINST (?) LIMIT 1
```

As understand I will compare first 3 words in `TextToCheckIn` against php array. But do not understand what i will get. Reading here http://www3.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/mysql/manual_Fulltext_Search.html

> For every row in a table it returns relevance - a similarity measure between the text in that row (in the columns that are part of the collection) and the query.

Seems it is exactly what is necessary... need to check

Comment: By storing rows in that fashion, you are making it harder to run queries on your data. You could split `black yellow white red` into four rows, or even four FKs in a many:many table that points to a colour table. Either way, counting the number of matches will be much easier.

Comment: My idea is a bit different. In question 3 words are only as example. Actually i want to find if in mysql is very similar text comparing to user's input. With Jonny 5 answer i can set/decide similarity level. In my situation it appears reasonably to check first 12 words. So with `MATCH... AGAINST` i check similarity....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [Boolean Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

If you match without operators `+` `-` against such as `green red blue` all rows are returned, where a record contains at least one word: `green` or `red` or `blue`.

`IN BOOLEAN MODE` and without operators each matched word will score `1`. So if there's a record matching two out of the three words it would score `2`.

To get the rows with at least 2 score:

```
SELECT *,
MATCH (`TextToCheckIn`) AGAINST ('green red blue' IN BOOLEAN MODE) `score`
FROM `my_tab` WHERE 
MATCH (`TextToCheckIn`) AGAINST ('green red blue' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
HAVING `score` >= 2
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

In [Natural Language mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) scoring works completely different. Think it's primarily based on [BM25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

---

On large datasets boolean fulltext search (using a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)) usually outperforms `REGEXP` or `LIKE` by far if matching words *somewhere* in the text. Would only use like/regexp for matching from the initial such as `REGEXP '^word'` or `LIKE 'word%'` - if an index can be utilized.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't MySQL for to test next query. You try something:

```
SELECT Id, TextToCheckIn REGEXP "(${word1})|(${word2})" AS Flag
FROM table
WHERE Flag = 1
```

Comment: Isnt `REGEXP` slow? Similarly to `LIKE`?

Comment: Yes. It will work slow. But it'll faster than a cycle in php. For hiload you should refactor your database schema with three tables or to use predefined sets http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html